# Every simply ordered set imbeds into a linear continuum?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, connectedness

I was thinking recently about a seemingly simple way to construct, for any order topology, a linear continuum into which it imbeds. I have read about a concept that seems similar to this idea called the Dedekind-MacNeille completion, but that deals with posets more generally and different techniques, so I am left a bit uncertain.

Take any simply ordered set, $(X,<)$. For each member $a\times b$ of the set $S=\{x\times y| (x,y)=\emptyset,x,y\in X\}$, we choose a copy of $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb Q_a$, which is just all the rationals with a little $a$ subscript. We assume for simplicity's sake each $Q_a$ is naturally disjoint from $X$. Now, we define a simply ordered set $(X',<')$, where $X'=X\cup_{x\in S}\mathbb Q_x$, and $<'$ agrees with $<$ on $X$. For any $r_x$ and any $y\in X'$, we have $r_x<'y$ if $y\geq \textrm{succ}(x)$, and $r_x>'y$ otherwise. For any $r_x\neq s_x$, we have $r_x<'s_x$ if $r<s$ in $\mathbb Q$ and $r_x>'s_x$ otherwise. For any $r_x$ and $s_y$ where $x\neq y$, we have $r_x<'s_y$ if $x<y$ and $r_x>'s_y$ otherwise. The effect of all of this is that $(X',<')$ is essentially an extension of $(X,<)$ which has a dense order.

The idea from here is just to further 'fill in' the gaps using Dedekind cuts on $(X',<')$, and produce a space $(X'',<'')$, which contains $(X',<')$ as a subspace (and hence also $(X,<)$ as a subspace) and has the l.u.b. property. So $(X'',<'')$ should be the desired linear continuum. I see no obvious reason why this construction shouldn't work, but I can't shake the feeling some degree of hand-waviness is at play.

Is the idea here valid? If so, how can it be made more rigorous?

A final question (assuming that this construction works on some level), can we talk reasonably about a minimal linear continuum containing $(X,<)$? In special cases perhaps? And if so, do these minimal linear continua have any of the typical uniqueness properties (unique up to homeomorphism or order-isomorphism, for instance)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ll begin by presenting the first part of your construction in a somewhat more compact form and demonstrating a problem with it.

Let $\langle X,\le_X\rangle$ be a LOTS, and let $$S=\{x\in X:x\text{ has an immediate successor in }\langle X,\le_X\rangle\}\;;$$ if $x\in S$, I’ll write $x^+$ for the successor of $x$. Let $\hat X=\{\langle x,q\rangle\in X\times\Bbb Q:x\in S\text{ or }q=0\}$, and let $\preceq$ be the lexicographic order on $\hat X$, so that $\langle x,p\rangle\preceq\langle y,q\rangle$ iff either $x<_Xy$, or $x=y$ and $p\le q$. Clearly $\langle\hat X,\preceq\rangle$ is a dense linear order, and the map

$$\iota:X\to\{\langle x,q\rangle\in\hat X:q=0\}:x\mapsto\langle x,0\rangle$$

is an order-isomorphism: $x\le_Xy$ iff $\langle x,0\rangle\preceq\langle y,0\rangle$ for $x,y\in X$. This is essentially your construction up to the point at which you want to take Dedekind cuts.

We’d like $\iota$ to be a topological embedding. It’s clear that $\iota$ is an open bijection from $X$ to $\hat X_0=\{\langle x,0\rangle\in\hat X:q=0\}$. To show that $\iota$ is continuous, let $\langle x,p\rangle,\langle y,q\rangle\in\hat X$ with $\langle x,p\rangle\prec\langle y,q\rangle$, and let $I=\big(\langle x,p\rangle,\langle y,q\rangle\big)$, so that $I\cap X_0$ is a basic open set in $\hat X_0$; we must show that $\iota^{-1}[I\cap\hat X_0]$ is open in $X$. If $p\ge 0$ and $q\le 0$ this is no problem: in that case $\iota^{-1}[I\cap\hat X_0]=(x,y)$. It’s also no problem if $p\ge 0$ and $q<0$: in that case $y\in S$, and $\iota^{-1}[I\cap\hat X_0]=(x,y]=(x,y^+)$. If $p<0$, however, we have a problem, because in that case $\langle x,0\rangle\in I$, and $\iota^{-1}[I\cap\hat X_0]$ is either $[x,y)$ or $[x,y^+)$, depending on $q$, and this is open in $X$ iff $x=\min X$, or $x$ has an immediate predecessor in $X$, neither of which can be guaranteed.

The basic idea will work, but we have to be a bit more careful in constructing $\hat X$. In particular, we also have to pay attention to whether an $x\in X$ has an immediate predecessor in $X$ (which I’ll denote by $x^-$ if it exists). Let

$$P=\{x\in X:x\text{ has an immediate predecessor in }\langle X,\le_X\rangle\}\;,$$

and let

$$\hat X=\{\langle x,q\rangle\in X\times\Bbb Q:q=0,\text{ or }x\in S\text{ and }q>0,\text{ or }x\in P\text{ and }q<0\}\;.$$

As before let $\preceq$ be the lexicographic order on $\hat X$; it’s not hard to check that $\langle\hat X,\preceq\rangle$ is dense, and now you’ll find that it’s possible to carry out the argument that I attempted above to show that $\iota$ is not just an order embedding, but in fact a homeomorphism from $X$ onto $\hat X_0$.

If you now imitate the construction of $\Bbb R$ from $\Bbb Q$ by Dedekind cuts, some of the new points will fill in the gaps in the intervals $\big(\langle x,0\rangle,\langle x^+,0\rangle\big)$ for $x\in S$ and the intervals $\big(\langle x^-,0\rangle,\langle x,0\rangle\big)$ for $x\in P$, as if we had simply defined $\hat X$ to be

$$\hat X=\{\langle x,r\rangle\in X\times\Bbb R:r=0,\text{ or }x\in S\text{ and }0<r\le1,\\\text{ or }x\in P\text{ and }r<0\}\;.$$

And if $\langle X,\le_X\rangle$ has any gaps, there will also be new points filling the corresponding gaps in $\langle\hat X,\preceq\rangle$. At this point you will indeed have a complete dense linear order containing a copy of the LOTS $X$.

Comment: To understand, each $x\in S$ corresponds to a $y\in P$ (both ends of a gap). So when we "fill the gap", we first fill in a copy of positive rationals on the "x" side and a copy of the negative rationals on the "y" side (the two half copies of the rationals abut each other "in the middle".  And then we plug any unfilled Dedekind cuts (including the Dedekind cut "in the middle"). Maybe I missed something, but the final description of $\hat X$ with reals still has an unfilled Dedekind cut "in the middle"?  Would it be easier to add a single copy of $\Bbb Q$ in each jump (Henno's terminology)?

Comment: One more question: The order embedding from $X$ to $\hat X_0$ is a homeomorphism.  Does passing to the Dedekind completion also give a homeomorphism from $X$ to its image?

Comment: @PatrickR: Yes, what I did was overkill; doing it that way just made checking continuity especially easy, since the work was basically already done in the initial unsuccessful attempt. But you can certainly just cut off the negative rationals below points of $S$, in effect inserting a copy of $\Bbb Q$ (and after completion a copy of $(0,1)$ between $x$ and $x^+$. That is, after all, what I did: I just cut $\Bbb Q$ in half, so to speak. As for your last question, $\hat X$ is dense in the completion, so it inherits the right topology, and therefore so does $\hat X_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  But what I was getting at is about the last formula: $\hat X=\{\langle x,r\rangle\in X\times\Bbb R:r=0,\text{ or }x\in S\text{ and }r>0,\text{ or }x\in P\text{ and }r<0\}$.  If $x<y$ with $x\in S$ and $y\in P$, then $\{\langle x,r\rangle:r>0\}$ has no supremum in $\hat X$ (the elements immediately after are the points $\langle y,r\rangle$with $r<0$, with themselves have no infimum).  So $\hat X$ is not complete.  It's missing the "point in the middle".

Comment: @PatrickR: Ah, okay: I was concentrating on the rest of your comment and didn’t even notice that bit. You’re right, of course; I need to replace $\Bbb R$ with $(0,1]$, say, for $x\in S$.

Answer (score 4):

A classic fact is that a LOTS $X$ (a linearly ordered set in the order topology) is connected iff it has no gaps and no jumps.

A gap is a non-trivial (both sets non-empty) partition $A \cup B = X$, such that $A < B$ (all $a \in A$ and all $b \in B$ obey $a < b$) such that $A$ has no maximum and $B$ has no minimum. (This is closely related to Dedekind cuts).

A jump is a pair of point $x < y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle =\emptyset$, so that no point $z$ obeys $x < z < y$.

So starting with any LOTS $X$ we can form its order completion (aka Dedekind-McNeill completion) $\hat{X}$. (Adding a minimum and a maximum now, if not already present, gives an order compactification already). We've gotten rid of all gaps now, but jumps need to be filled. I suppose we can get away with filling these with copies of $[0,1]$, which gives us an essentially unique connected space in which $X$ embeds, but $X$ need not be dense in it, like it is in $\hat{X}$.

My hunch is that we probably cannot always embed *densely*. It is known that the Sorgenfrey line has no connected space in which it embeds but that's "only" a GO space (generalised ordered) not a LOTS.

Comment: Yes, in a space with 'jumps', imbedding densely seems implausible. In my question, I present a different way of imbedding the set in a linear continuum. First the 'jumps' in $(X,<)$ are filled and then the 'gaps' (at least that's the idea). Does the construction outlined seem valid to you? Should it agree (in some sense) with the linear continuum you have constructed in your answer? Also, could you elaborate a bit on the 'unique' part of the imbedding you have mentioned?